# Jquery Validation not Working

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I have a problem with my jquery, I've researched different jquery validations and tried different format but it still not working and also I have used different `<script src>` but no use. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdogjck8/2/)

```
<form id="myform">
    <select name="state" id="select1" required>
        <option value="">Select a State</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
    <select name="entity" id="select2" required>
        <option value="LLC">LLC</option>
        <option value="corp">Corporation</option>
    </select>
    <br>Entity Name
    <input type="text" id="input4" name="entityName" value="" required/>Alt Name
    <input type="text" id="input5" value="" name="altName" required/>Business Description
    <input type="text" id="input6" name="busDesc" placeholder="Any legal business" required/>
    <br>FYE
    <select name="month" id="select3" required>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option selected value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select name="day" id="select4" required>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option selected value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <br>Taxation:
    <select name="tax" required>
        <option value="RT">A</option>
        <option value="Corpo">B</option>
        <option value="SC">C</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="btn5" name="submit" value="SUBMIT ORDER" />
</form>
```

```js
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        state: "required",
        corp: "required",
        entityName: "required",
        altName: "required",
        busDesc: "required",
        month: "required",
        day: "required",
        tax: "required",
    },
});
```

Comment: Please include your code within the question. A jsfiddle link is great, but if that site goes down your question would be unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

`<input type="button" id="btn5" name="submit" value="SUBMIT ORDER" />`

To

`<input type="submit" id="btn5" name="submit" value="SUBMIT ORDER" />`

Answer (score 0):

`#corpform` must exist and must be a form and your button must be a `type="submit"`.

Then, do not insert validate.min.js and validate.js: .min.js is the production version and .js is the source.

At least, give to your fields names that mean something. No input1, input2, input3 but entityName, altName, etc.